# How to find user current location?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, codeigniter

I am trying to figure out how I can detect the visitor's location, so I can geocode into latitude and longtitude so I can query a database and find the user's distance from a few fixed locations.

hopefully the same method works on iphones too...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an API such as http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php once you have found the user's IP address with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. It seems that it can get the user's city, if that is accurate enough for your latitude/longitude.

Comment: does ipinfodb gives the results in the same units as used in google maps api? like (1.234, 0.123) lat/lng pair

Answer (score 5):

Below is a link to the HTML 5 Geolocation API.  Start there.

[Geolocation API - W3C Editor's Draft](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html)

You can scroll down and see an example implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the browser geolocation method mentioned above (please note geolocation is NOT part of the HTML5 spec) or if the browser doesn't support it then use yahoo placefinder to look up the users location from a country & zip/postcode.

This way your app works for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$country=file_get_contents('http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=');

echo $country;

// Reformat the data returned (Keep only country and country abbr.)

$only_country=explode (" ", $country);

echo "Country : ".$only_country[1]." ".substr($only_country[2],0,4);
```